# Expanding the textarea height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I created this codes to make automatic expanding of textarea height when the text inside exceeded to height of the textarea but this only works in jsfiddle but when i run this in my project this doesnt work. does anyone can help me? Thanks.

```js
 $("#ta").keyup(function (e) {
        autoheight(this);
    });
    
    function autoheight(a) {
        if (!$(a).prop('scrollTop')) {
            do {
                var b = $(a).prop('scrollHeight');
                var h = $(a).height();
                $(a).height(h - 5);
            }
            while (b && (b != $(a).prop('scrollHeight')));
        };
        $(a).height($(a).prop('scrollHeight') + 20);
    }
    
    autoheight($("#ta"));
```

```css
 #ta {
        width:250px;
        min-height:116px;
        max-height:300px;
        resize:none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
```

Comment: try press F12 and tell us if there is an error in the console, if so please provide the error.

Comment: have you included jquery min js on the top of the page? check your console for more info

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jquery then you have to load Jquery library and add your code in the document ready or window load. Below is the updated code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>

#ta {
    width:250px;
    min-height:116px;
    max-height:300px;
    resize:none;
}

</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ta").keyup(function (e) {
    autoheight(this);
    console.log("log");
});
});

function autoheight(a) {
    if (!$(a).prop('scrollTop')) {
        do {
            var b = $(a).prop('scrollHeight');
            var h = $(a).height();
            $(a).height(h - 5);
        }
        while (b && (b != $(a).prop('scrollHeight')));
    };
    $(a).height($(a).prop('scrollHeight') + 20);
}

autoheight($("#ta"));
</script>

</head>
<body>

<textarea id="ta"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi . I tried this code and only works in chrome . I need it in internet explorer

Comment: while using the jquery you need to be connected to internet because link for jquery is CDN so make sure your internet is connected.

Comment: @Jivenlans Tabien, Unfortunately i don't have IE 11 on my machine but will try and get you back on this.

Comment: I think You're running in a compatibility mode of some sort, To disable the compatibility mode, add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> in your html header.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me in IE 11 as well, try the below js fiddle link in IE -

https://jsfiddle.net/wp3wvuj2/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ta").keyup(function (e) {
autoheight(this);
console.log("log");
});
});

 function autoheight(a) {
if (!$(a).prop('scrollTop')) {
    do {
        var b = $(a).prop('scrollHeight');
        var h = $(a).height();
        $(a).height(h - 5);
    }
    while (b && (b != $(a).prop('scrollHeight')));
};
$(a).height($(a).prop('scrollHeight') + 20);
}

autoheight($("#ta"));
```